# Excel #REF error with OFFSET formmula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, ref

I have an OFFSET formula referencing another sheet. The active row is deleted and the remaining rows shift up when i click button 1. everything works but i keep getting a #REF error when the rows shift up. Is there a better formula to use to avoid such error?

Here is what I have:

[Active Cell is C7, clicking button 1 will clear that row on a a different sheet and shift the bottom rows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpd51.png)

[Here's what happens after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBjrs.png)

Comment: Those Shift Up are basically delete operations and hence causing the #REF! error. First argument of Offset function is reference and its deleted or removed, it shows #REF!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
=index(sheet2!c:c, 2+$a$34)
```

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to do the trick, care to elaborate how this works?